# Django, how can I convert Google analytics data to int

Tags: python-3.x, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, django-2.0

I am pretty new to Django and python

I am currently working on a project. I was thinking is there a way to convert the data I am getting from Google Analytics to an variable.

Google analytics api gets the data, you can put it in the metrics etc

```
'metrics': [
                            {
                                "expression": "ga:pageviews"
                            },

                        ]
```

So you get 100 as the result, but I want that "ga:pageviews" to be a int. So I can edit that 100. And add 1 view to that total with a button for example. I don`t want the edited view to be sent to Google Analytics (it is now possible anyway I guess)

But I was curious if this is possible, how could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Json is a string so your value is returning as a string. You will need to covert it.

```
def int_or_0(value):
    try:
        return int(value)
    except:
        return 0
```

Comment: So I have to pass the ga:pageviews in value?

Comment: Yes exactly it should return to you an int.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late answer. But it is giving me an error: "Invalid value at 'report_requests[0].metrics[0].expression' (TYPE_STRING), 0">